# SQL select from header table where detail table rows have multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I am trying to put together a query to fetch data for a report.

I am not a newcomer to SQL, but I will admit that I really only make very light use of it. I have a small bag of tricks which I manage to make go a long way.

I have a feeling that I might be needing a nested query to accomplish my goal this time, which  I have never attempted to use before.

This is an extremely simplified version of my problem.

I have 2 tables: `employee-header` and `employee-details`.

The is a one to many relationship between these tables (1 header to many details)

The header contains contact information about the employee, one row per employee, each employee with an `id` - the primary key.

The details table contains multiple rows per employee, each representing a record of a `training-type` achieved by the employee. Each row references the employee's `id` from the header table.

My goal is to SELECT a list of employees and their training types WHERE the employee has multiple `training-types`... i.e. the employee has both training-type-1 and traing-type-2

I guess the thing that's tripping me up is that there can be an arbitrary number of training types, so instead of each training type having it's own column, they instead have their own row.

I've tried to make my problem as clear as possible, and simplify it enough to make it attainable... the truth is that it's actually one part of a much more complex pre-existing query that also performs several date operations on the detail row to see whether the training is valid, expired, or archived (an expired training item that has been reattained since expiry). I am happy to provide any more information that could help if required.

How would I be able to fetch a result set that meets my needs?

Edit:

In an attempt to make my problem clearer, here is some sample data that illustrates the situation.

`employee-header` table:

```
emp-id | employee-name
------------------
   1   | Employee A
   2   | Employee B
   3   | Employee C
```

`employee-detail` table:

```
det-id | emp-id | training-type
-------------------------------
   1   |   1    | forklift
   2   |   1    | welding
   3   |   1    | lifting
   4   |   2    | forklift
   5   |   2    | lifting
   6   |   3    | welding
   7   |   3    | forklift
```

So if I wanted to select the `emp-id` and `employee-name` from the header, of all employees that had a `training-type` of both "forklift" AND "welding" what would my query need to be.

Comment: If *multiple* means *more than 1*, put `GROUP BY id ... HAVING COUNT(training_id) > 1` into your sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by a sub-query:

```
SELECT h.id, h.employee_name, d.training-type
FROM employee-header h INNER JOIN employee-details d ON h.id = d.id
WHERE h.id IN -- here is the sub-query
(SELECT id from employee-details 
 WHERE training-type IN ('forklift','welding') 
 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT training-type) = 2)
```

When you need to select the exact number on matches you can use `IN` clause in the selection criteria and then just use the HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT training-type) matching the number of requested values

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I'm not sure this is quite what I'm looking for, I'm not looking for just a multiple-rows (count), but rather multiple rows that have specific values for one of the fields... Have added some sample data to my question illustrate my problem more clearly.