# sql select master records based on ANDing multiple detail records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have master and detail tables as described below (with representative data). I want to select (mysql-compliant) Student.id for students that have an "A" in both Biology and Chemistry.

```
Students                      grades
id     name                   id   student_id  class        grade
1      ken                    1    1           Biology      A
2      beth                   2    1           Chemistry    A
3      joe                    3    1           Math         B
                              4    2           Biology      A
                              5    2           Chemistry    A
                              6    2           Math         A
                              7    3           Biology      B
                              8    3           Chemistry    A
                              9    3           Math         A
```

Currently, I'm just pulling in all the data into my program (java) but figure there's got to be a way in SQL to get the right records.

The results I'm looking for from the data above would be 1 & 2 (ken and beth). I've tried a few variations using joins and inner selects but can't quite get it to work. My main problem seems to be I'm ANDing my detail records eg., `...where grades.class='Biology' and grades.grade='A'`

I took a look at [SQL select from header table where detail table rows have multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614699/sql-select-from-header-table-where-detail-table-rows-have-multiple-values) but that didn't quite get me where I need to be.

Assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select s.id from students as s 
inner join grades as g on s.id=g.student_id
group by s.id
having max(case when g.class='Biology' and g.grade='A' then 1 else 0 end)=1
and
having max(case when g.class='Chemistry' and g.grade='A' then 1 else 0 end)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
select g.student_id
from grades g
where g.class in ('Biology', 'Chemistry') and g.grade = 'A'
group by g.student_id
having count(distinct class) = 2;
```

Notes:

- A `join` is not necessary because the `grades` table has the student id.
- The `where` clause only gets records where a student has an `'A'` in either class.
- The `having` guarantees that a student has an `'A'` in both classes.

I should note that there is an alternative method that uses `join` but not `group by`:

```
select gb.student_id
from grades gb join
     grades gc
     on gb.student_id = gc.student_id and
        gb.class = 'Biology' and gc.class = 'Chemistry' and
        gb.grade = 'A' and gc.grade = 'A';
```

This works -- and the performance might even be better.  I like the `group by` and `having` approach because it is more flexible.

Comment: Interesting - never thought of joining a table to itself (i'll have to remember that in the future). Since my ultimate goal is to have interchangeable grades with the classes, this seems to be the better fit for my circumstance. Given that mysql allows 61 joins in a single statement, this should do me fine.  Thanks!